# How to Delete command files in Oracle SQL*Plus?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Is it possible to delete file created using "edit" command in SQL*Plus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`host`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/HOST.html) command to issue a `del` or `rm` command, depending on the client operating system.

SQL*Plus has no built-in way of detecting the client operating system, so if you want scripts to be portable, you will have to script a workaround such as examining the value of `v$session.program` for the current session.